# Can I use my Summary of Payments as proof of Health Expenditure?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction

Last year was an expensive one for my family health-care wise. I have downloaded all my family's Summary of Payments from my insurer, and I was hoping to keep hold of those as my proof of expenditure for my taxes.

I can't seem to find a statement one way or the other on the IRS website about this, but it seems fairly reasonable that the "Your Share" column suffices as proof of what I spent out of pocket?

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking for what is the documentation you need to substantiate the medical expenses deduction (Schedule A line 1) then yes. You need to show that you actually paid these amounts and that you have not been reimbursed for them (say from your FSA, or some other coverage). See the [Schedule A instructions](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040sca#en_US_2022_publink53061xd0e516).

Comment: @keshlam same criteria is used for HSA and FSA eligibility, so one may need to know it even if it is not enough to be deductible on one's return.

Comment: Of course that won't include costs for things you didn't submit to the insurance company. And the cost of the insurance itself is a medical expense. Even including those, it is rare for medical expenses to rise to a level high enough to qualify for the deduction.... rare enough that I've never seen any point in tracking it. (That may change now that I've taken one retirement and haven't yet sought other employment.) [SE insists we can only fix typos in comments by deleting and recreating them. Sigh